# Configure via msi

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.7

I have wix script that can create regitry value if it was specified during execution:

"msiexec /i my.msi MYPROP=value"

script:

```
      <Component Id='RegistryConfigServer' Win64='$(var.Def_Component_win64)' Permanent="yes" >
        <Condition>MYPROP</Condition>
        <RegistryKey Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\$(var.Def_ManufacturerName)' ForceCreateOnInstall='yes' ForceDeleteOnUninstall='no' >
          <RegistryKey Key='$(var.Def_ProductName)' ForceCreateOnInstall='yes' ForceDeleteOnUninstall='no' >
                    <RegistryValue Type="string"  Name='Server' Value="[MYPROP]" />
          </RegistryKey>
        </RegistryKey>
      </Component>
```

It works. But if I run first: "msiexec /i my.msi" and after that "msiexec /i my.msi MYPROP=value" - the registry key is not created! Why? Can I change behavior to create the key?

Answer (score 0):

Your component is already installed and it's state won't be reevaluate.

If you need to reevaluate the component state, you should mark the component as transitive.

But there could be a side effect: if you'll start "msiexec /i my.msi MYPROP=value" at first and after that "msiexec /i my.msi" - your component will be removed.